# Strongly typed AppSettings Configuration in ASP.NET 5

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-core

When using WebApi 2 my web.config was

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="RavenHQ" connectionString="Url=http://localhost:8080;Database=ModelFarmDb" />    
</connectionStrings>
```

For ASP.NET 5.0, I can't work out how to write the config.json file to do the same thing.

I've tried

```
{
    "Data": {
        "RavenHQ": {
            ConnectionString: "Url=http://localhost:8080;Database=ModelFarmDb"
        }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work. Any suggestions on how to directly map the web.config sections to config.json so as not to break other libraries that assume a web.config?

The app is running under IIS Express locally and is a web app on Azure.

Many thanks!

Comment: If you have libraries still using `ConfigurationManager` to access Web.config in ASP.NET 5, you should ideally rewrite them to use `IOptions<T>` instead, where type T represents the type containing your settings above.

Comment: I got the exception "No connection string named 'RavenHQ' could be found in the application config file.". In the .NET 5 project, I 'm using some dll references  of projects which have the web.config file.

Comment: If you have no control over these DLL references and you really need to use them then you may need to add the connection string in both places.

Comment: In my dll references of projects, I have defined the connection string. Do you have other ideal?

Answer (score 2):

You accomplish this in asp.net 5.0 in a different way. I used json file for this example. If you need add xml file just use these package `Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Xml` and use `.AddXmlFile()` method

> This example uses beta 7

Create an AppSetting class

```
public class AppSetting
{
    public string Setting1 { get; set; }

    public string Setting2 { get; set; }

}
```

In your startup file add the json file with the configuration on this example is call config.json

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{       

    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddXmlFile("thefilename")
        .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

    builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
```

Then you need to add the app service your AppSetting class so it can be injected 
for later use

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
```

Then in your controller or where ever you need the configuraton inject the `IOptions<AppSettings>`

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{

    private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

    public SampleController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {            
        _appSettings = appSettings.Value;            
    }

}
```

and this is how the json looks like

```
{
  "AppSetting": {
    "Setting1": "Foo1",
    "Setting1": "Foo1"
  }
}
```

I took these peaces of code from [live.asp.net](https://github.com/aspnet/live.asp.net) in github

Comment: Thanks for this, been trying to solve this for a day! I'm on beta8 and this still works.

Comment: No problem. Can you mark the question as answer is all work