# Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type string and Enum

Tags: c#, enums, operators

I have the following code where `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["O1M:SeveritaMinimaLogger"]` contains `string`. I want to compare it with an `Enum` but I get error:

> Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and `severity`(is my Enum type)

```cs
if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["O1M:SeveritaMinimaLogger"] >= severity)
{ 
    //to do....
}
```

Comment: Everything that's saved inside your `AppSettings` (assuming it's a config file) will always be a string, and not "correctly" typed, so you'll need to parse the value (using [`Enum.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=net-5.0) or better `Enum.TryParse`), or use [strongly typed appsettings configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33142052/9363973)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the configuration manager value is a numerical value stored as a string e.g. "1", then you would need to convert both values into an `int` type to perform your `>=` comparison.

With

```
enum Severity
{
   Low = 0,
   Medium,
   High
}
    
if (Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["O1M:SeveritaMinimaLogger"]) >= Convert.ToInt16(Severity.Medium))
{
   ...
}
```